# Testing if an object is undefined or not without halting Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, undefined

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but from googling, I have yet to find a solution for this that works for me

I'm writing a program that parse a JSON from a public API from [splatoon2.ink](https://splatoon2.ink/data/coop-schedules.json). it is so far so good. but there is one thing that i'm unable to solve until now

There is a property in the JSON that tells you what kind of weapons is available at the current schedule. I could easily called it by telling it to look on :

```
body.details[0].weapons[0].weapon.name
```

However, during certain condition, there are some special weapons. But instead of only changing the name, the API changes the object to :

```
body.details[0].weapons[0].coop_special_weapon.name
```

as such every time my program calls the `weapon.name` object, Node.js halted saying that the object is `undefined`

so I write a simple if statement like below :

```
if (coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].weapon.name == undefined){
      var currentWeapon1 = coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].coop_special_weapon.name;
} else {
      var currentWeapon1 = coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].weapon.name;}
```

however, Node.js keep halting because it said the `weapon.name` object is undefined. which is true it is undefined. but I wanted the if statement to continue execution so that it could take the property of the `coop_special_weapon.name` object instead.

so how could I detect an undefined object without crashing node.js?

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: problem is, if weapon is undefined, then trying to access `weapon.name` will throw an error ... either use try/catch, or test the validity of all intermediate properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misjudged it by a bit. It halted because `weapon` itself is `undefined`, and thus, `name` cannot be acquired from it. Change your condition to this:

```
if (coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].weapon == undefined) {
  var currentWeapon1 = coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].coop_special_weapon.name;
} else {
  var currentWeapon1 = coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0].weapon.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `weapon` is `undefined`, so getting the `name` fails. You can shorten your code a bit, by using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
const weapons = coopSchedule.details[0].weapons[0];
const weapon = (weapons.weapon || weapons.coop_special_weapon).name;
```